# Node.js - Writing to file - permission denied

Tags: node.js, file-permissions

I am using `express-winston` to write to my log file in `/var/log/project/project.log`. However, I keep getting

`Error: EACCES: permission denied, open /var/log/project/project.log`.

Does anyone know a way around this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: first i would check permissions on the file.  recently on linux server I had to check what user the node.js process was running under and then had to allow that user to have access to the file for something similar to work.  if you can add more detail to your post that would help.

Comment: Have you set the permissions for the user running the node app? As a quick workaround, you can also try running the node server with sudo.